# "Code not properly formatted as code" when attempting to blockquote a table

Tags: bug, markdown, tables, blockquote

In a recent answer, I was attempting to cite a specific line in a table from the official documentation. Due to its formatting, I thought it would be better to format the quoted section as a table. This prompted the "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" which blocked the edit. Images of the markdown editor and the preview below.

| Image |
| --- |
| [image: In Markdown] |
| [image: From the preview] |

As this blocks the edit, I ended up removing the quoted section entirely, choosing to leave just the link to the documentation. However, in more complex cases where quoting a table is needed, and thus formatting it as such for readability, would be more important this could be an issue, especially considering that the section copied from a link should be in block quotes as per [the referencing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Are there any existing guidelines for this or could this be unintended behaviour?

Markdown that caused the issue in text:

```
>|Specifier| Description|
>|-|-|
>|%i |Minutes, numeric (00..59)|
```

Comment: Maybe try inserting a space after each `>`?

Comment: I swear, with all the different causes of this bug, we either need a tag for them or a canonical question with a list... it's so hard to keep track of why it happens in different cases.

Comment: @SamuelLiew just tried it and confirmed that adding a space after each `>` worked for this particular case

Comment: All that said, there really ought to be an existing duplicate for that question... I just can't find anything really accurate.

Comment: Could you please include the markdown code as text?

Comment: @DonaldDuck added it to the bottom of the post. Also just tried it and it still caused the issue (if there is no space between the `>` and `|`)